# show Image that stored on filesystem

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've try many ways to show Image that stored on my FileSystem but not work. last i try with Intervention Image package, but it still not showing, just show icon blank image not the image itself.

This is my View:

```
<header>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <h4>Detail Keluhan</h4><hr>
        <h5 style="color: gray">{{$keluhan->username}}</h5>
        <img src="{{ route('product.image', ['ttd_setuju' => $keluhan->ttd_setuju]) }}" alt="ttd_setuju"/>
    </div>
</header>
```

This is my Route:

```
Route::get('image/{ttd_setuju}', ['as'=>'product.image', function($ttd_setuju) {
    return Image::make('app/public/img/ttd'.'/'.$ttd_setuju)->response('png');
}]);
```

for information, i stored it on app/public/img/ttd
and it's name on table 'keluhan' in my DB
how can i solve this guys ? please kindly help any other way its okay if its work

Comment: can you inspect your web page and see what is the url of the image that show on source code

Comment: it said Image source not readable

Comment: I've tried to do this for experiment to show image like usual <img src="user/christianus/picture/Lighthouse.jpg"> and its not work too BUT i try with <img src="{{asset('img/ttd/2.png')}}"> it shown... what wrong with this ??

Comment: whay don't you try something like,
<img src='/img/ttd'.'/'.$keluhan->ttd_setuju.'.png' alt="ttd_setuju"/>

Comment: i've too bro & still nothing work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i fix the problem with this one

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/ttd/'.$keluhan->gambar) }}" height="200" width="250"/>
```

Using asset.